# django_heroku ModuleNotFoundError although correctly installed

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am making a `django` project and using `css` files but while deploying to heroku i got:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
```

I have installed all things for django-heroku...and at end it says:

```py
Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

but im using css files and by disabling this applicaton error occure 
plz help ,,,i almost gave up im trying for 2 days

HERE is the program when i do git push heroku master where error occurs

```
remote:            import django_heroku
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_heroku'
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to fjblogs.
remote:
remote:
remote:    To https://git.heroku.com/fjblogs.git
remote:     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
remote:    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fjblogs.git'
```

Comment: Are you sure you `pip install django-heroku` and it worked?

Comment: yes i did it again too and it said ...already exists ...im really worried as ive completed my site but this is a big problem for me...